# Can I marry Photoshop scripting with frontend workflow like Gulp or Grunt?

Tags: javascript, image-processing, frontend, photoshop-script

In our frontend build scheme we need to resize images for srcset attribute.
I've tried to use gulp-responsive and other Gulp and Grunt plugins, but quality of result images is unacceptable.

So, can I use Photoshop scripts from Gulp or Grunt task, or, maybe, shell script?
All I need is run Photoshop, do stuff and exit.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

It is possible with Photoshop, see this [guide](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/photoshop/pdfs/photoshop_scripting_guide.pdf) but you should definitely consider switching to [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) – everything your said works with it very well. It's much easier to learn scripting for ImageMagic than for Photophop, It saves you hours, but of course it's on your own choice.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I've tried ImageMagick, but quality

Comment: is the same as when using Gulp.

Comment: May be you're wrong with command arguments? I never had problems with quality when used IM.

Comment: something like this `convert rose.png -resize 50% rose_min.png`